# Prohibiting AD domain logon with Group Policy

Tags: login, windows-server-2012, active-directory, group-policy

Does anyone know if it is possible to configure a Group Policy in an AD environment to display a message when an account is used for login to the domain with a message such as:

> *"logon is prohibited with account on AD domain"*

Comment: What exactly do you want to prohibit?

Comment: **Non GPO Method:** *From AD Users and Computers* just go to the account **`Properties`** | **`Account`** tab | click the **`Logon Hours`** button, and then in the **`Logon Hours for <account>`** window, select the appropriate days and time and then select the **`Logon Denied`** for that time period at which point the timeslot will become white—select all the slots and time frames to prohibit domain logon with this account. See here for a screen shot of the options: https://i.imgur.com/MQRQ53Y.png. Plus the [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754934(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

## You can't.

If you deny logon to a user, they're unable to get beyond the sign in screen, and therefore no custom script, message, etc. can be displayed. The message that is displayed to a user that is not authorized to logon is generic and not customizable.

Any message you might display would be shown *after they successfully logon,* in which case they wouldn't be denied logon after all.

---

If on the other hand you want **all** domain users to be denied logon (which I assume is *not* what you're asking, but I'm including it for the sake of completeness), then simply unjoin the machine from the domain.